# Changing permissions in sub folder from designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-on-prem, item-level-permissions

I have a Document Library in SharePoint on premise, with 2 levels of sub folders, like so:
- Document Library Clients A to C
  - Folder Client A
    - Folder Team xyz

When I change the value of a field in Folder Client A, I want to run a workflow on item changed, that will change the permissions in Folder Team xyz.

What I am doing is:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem is, the workflow just says Error Occurred, with no further explanations. Tried to look into ULS logs too but did not get anywhere. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I also had the same issue. It does not even seem to work when using the same concept but in a rest api call!

Comment: with rest api, when i do ​https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/roledefinitions​
 it gives <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
Cannot find resource for the request roledefinitions.
</m:message>
</m:error>